# Block SMS in Objective C for IPhone and access them in MY App

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, sms, block

Is there any way in which i can block the SMS Notification in Iphone application and access those SMS in my application.

I want to create a GPS SMS Blocker which will block SMS if the vehical in which mobile phone is kept is running and speed will be detected by the GPS.

If speed is 0. then SMS can be received else they will be kept in database of my app and no notification will be shown.

Comment: I'm pretty sure Apple doesn't let you meddle with things like sms.

Answer (score 3):

Nope you cant do that.  sms db is not accessible.

Remember the Sandbox concept of iOS. They will not allow you to access out of your app.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to put this on the App Store, then it is not possible.

If you want to make an app for jailbroken phones only, that's another story.